# ValueError: ENone is not a valid coordinate or range

Tags: python, openpyxl, named-ranges

I am newish to python and I am trying to make something that creates some code for me in another file based on data that is in a spreadsheet. All is well in my test project but for some reason when using a different Excel file I get an error that I can not figure out:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
File "demo.py", line 76, in <module>
    MakeFile()
  File "demo.py", line 28, in MakeFile
    step_type = sheet[f"D{row.value}"]
  File "C:....\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 287, in __getitem__
    min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row = range_boundaries(key)
  File "C:...\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\utils\cell.py", line 137, in range_boundaries
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: ENone is not a valid coordinate or range
```

My code:

```
def MakeFile():
xl_filepath = "C:...Desktop/myfile.xlsx"
wb = load_workbook(xl_filepath)
sheet = wb.active
with open("testfile2.py", "w") as f:

    f.write("some stuff before loop")        
  
    for row in sheet["A"]:
        step_type = sheet[f"D{row.value}"]
        if row.value is None:
            print("End of Steps")
            #raise Exception("Cell is blank")
        else:
            if step_type.value == "text":
                f.write("somestuff")                   
                print(row.value, step_type.value)

            elif step_type.value == "animation":
                f.write("somestuff")
                print(row.value, step_type.value)

            else:
                f.write("somestuff")
                print(row.value, step_type.value)

    f.write("somestuff after the loop")
 
    f.close()
 MakeFile()
```

Essentially the loop is completing and doing everything I expect except at the end it throws this error.

```
  ValueError: ENone is not a valid coordinate or range
```

and does not do the writing after e.g "somestuff after the loop". It does close the file and save what it has done otherwise...

An example of my workbook

[Example spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOc5d.png)

I am going through column "A" and for every step in there (indicated with a number) I am taking the corresponding value of "D" and then doing something with it depending on if it is "text", "animation", or "anything else". It does also handle the additional values well for example if a row has "video" in it then it goes and does what is expected with the "else".

Comment: Move `step_type = sheet[f"D{row.value}"]` inside `else:`

Comment: Youre a 100% right! Thank you so much!!!!